# Base64 background image not working unless written as 1 rule?

Tags: css

ClassB has a background color and a background image but classA only has the background color.

```
.classA {
    background-color: #F2EDE3
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,mydata");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
.classB {
    background: #F2EDE3 url('data:image/png;base64,mydata') repeat-x left bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after the [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) property for `.classA`:

```
background-color: #f2ede3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I add the semicolon to the end of your line that defines the background color for class A, it works (minus the image as its invalid):

```css
.classA {
    background-color: #F2EDE3;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,mydata");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
.classB {
    background: #F2EDE3 url('data:image/png;base64,mydata') repeat-x left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class='classA'>aaa</div>
<div class='classB'>bbb</div>
```